# random and time adequacy

Tags: java, android, random

I try to do my own version of "fruit ninja" for training based on this version : https://github.com/emmaguy/FruitNinja

I have done some minor changes. What I want to do is to affect different scores to the object in the "enum" in `fruittype`.

So, I add this function (in the aim to retrieve the current random value):

```
public static int currentrandom() {
    return random.nextInt(FruitType2.values().length );
}
```

and I add,

```
if (FruitType2.currentrandom()<=9) {
       score++;
} else {
       score=score-5;
   }
```

at the end of FruitProjectileManager.

Complete code for FruitProjectileManager:

```
public class FruitProjectileManager02 implements ProjectileManager {

    private final Random random2 = new Random();
    private final List<Projectile> fruitProjectiles =
            new ArrayList<Projectile>();
    private final SparseArray<Bitmap> bitmapCache;
    private Region clip;
    private int maxWidth;
    private int maxHeight;


    private String FruitTypen = "FruitType2";


    public FruitProjectileManager02(Resources r) {

        bitmapCache = new SparseArray<Bitmap>(FruitType2.values().length);

        for (FruitType2 t : FruitType2.values()) {
            bitmapCache.put(t.getResourceId(), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r, t.getResourceId(), new Options()));
        }
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (Projectile f : fruitProjectiles) {
            f.draw(canvas);
        }
    }

    public void update() {

        if (maxWidth < 0 || maxHeight < 0) {
            return;
        }
        if (random2.nextInt(1000) < 30) {
            fruitProjectiles.add(createNewFruitProjectile());
        }

        for (Iterator<Projectile> iter = fruitProjectiles.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {

            Projectile f = iter.next();
            f.move();
            if (f.hasMovedOffScreen()) {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    private FruitProjectile02 createNewFruitProjectile() {
        int angle = random2.nextInt(20) + 70;
        int speed = random2.nextInt(30) + 120;
        boolean rightToLeft = random2.nextBoolean();

        float gravity = random2.nextInt(6) + 8.0f;
        float rotationStartingAngle = random2.nextInt(360);
        float rotationIncrement = random2.nextInt(100) / 3.0f;

        if (random2.nextInt(1) % 2 == 0) {
            rotationIncrement *= -1;
        }

        return new FruitProjectile02(bitmapCache.get(FruitType2.randomFruit().getResourceId()), maxWidth, maxHeight,
                angle, speed, gravity, rightToLeft, rotationIncrement, rotationStartingAngle);
    }

    public void setWidthAndHeight(int width, int height) {
        this.maxWidth = width;
        this.maxHeight = height;
        this.clip = new Region(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public int testForCollisions(List<TimedPath> allPaths) {
        int score = 0;
        for (TimedPath p : allPaths) {
            for (Projectile f : fruitProjectiles) {
                if (!f.isAlive())
                    continue;
                Region projectile = new Region(f.getLocation());
                Region path = new Region();
                path.setPath(p, clip);

                if (!projectile.quickReject(path) && projectile.op(path, Region.Op.INTERSECT)) {
                    if (FruitType2.currentrandom() <= 9) {
                        score++;
                    } else {
                        score = score - 5;
                    }
                    f.kill();
                }
            }
        }
        return score;
    }
}
```

Complete code for FruitType:

```
public enum FruitType2 {
    T02(R.drawable.n002),
    T04(R.drawable.n004),
    T06(R.drawable.n006),
    T08(R.drawable.n008),
    T10(R.drawable.n010),
    T12(R.drawable.n012),
    T14(R.drawable.n014),
    T16(R.drawable.n016),
    T18(R.drawable.n018),
    T20(R.drawable.n020),


    OTHER1(R.drawable.n003),
    OTHER2(R.drawable.n007),
    OTHER3(R.drawable.n011);

    private final int resourceId;

    private FruitType2(int resourceId) {
        this.resourceId = resourceId;
    }

    public int getResourceId() {
        return resourceId;
    }

    private static final Random random = new Random();


    public static int currentrandom() {


        return random.nextInt(FruitType2.values().length);
    }


    public static FruitType2 randomFruit() {


        return FruitType2.values()[random.nextInt(FruitType2.values().length)];
    }
}
```

I understand the problem , the current random(when the fruit is generated) is not the same that the random when the fruit is sliced and my question is how to
solve this problem. I get no idea so if you have some clues, I am interested.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps i don't understand the problem, but why don't you store the random number in a variable? Later you can take the random number out of the variable.